# Use of 'in which'

Tags: word-usage

Is the use of 'in which' correct in this context?

...and **Fc** is the flux vector:

[image]

where **U** is the velocity vector, ρ  the density, p the pressure, E the total energy, and Vc=**V.n** the contravariant velocity, in which
**n** is the unit normal vector to the face.

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply

Comment: That part of it is correct. The "in which" refers to the sub equation Vc = U•n and the clause following "in which" explains what n is in that equation. However the variables E and p don't appear anywhere, are they used in another sub equation? A further point about the English is that your question is badly form'ed. It should read "Is the use of 'in which' correct in this context?" The order of the subject and verb are reversed to form a question in English.

Comment: As written I see "in which" as referring to the contravariant velocity, not the equation. You could replace the middle part by *..energy and Vc the contravariant velocity given by <equation>, in which n is .. and U is ..* As you are defining symbols after they are used, I would move U to the end. It might be clearer to define symbols first, eg Let U be the velocity vector, etc, and then give the two equations, with the Vc= equation before the Fc= one.

Comment: How can anyone without knowledge of such technicalities answer your question. You should ask this question on a suitable technical site.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer in which I invite you to consider the question and a parallel non-technical example.

The full equation is irrelevant to the question and the answer. The question relates to an expression,  U·n̂ , that contains symbols. Within the expression, each symbol has a meaning. “In which” refers the reader to the expression and the symbols that are within.

For the non-technical reader, consider the parallel example of the so-called Chinese curse "May you live in interesting times" **in which** “interesting" is a euphemism for “difficult”.

In conclusion, “In which” is clear, unambiguous and correct.

Comment: I accept Greybeard's alterations to the last paragraph of my answer. They are consistent with, but clearer than, my original.

Answer (score 0):

I will not say it's perfectly correct. "In which" here refers to n ,for some extent it is understandable. But ,if you use ,where "n" is unit Normal vector to the face , would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> in which n is the unit normal vector to the face.

In = **within**.

Which -> the referent of which is **U·n̂**